# Error - "java: cannot find symbol" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to run my project but IntelliJ IDEA version 13 shows some strange error message:

[image]

Now class file has some small cross at class icon.

But this code was compiled, I couldn't figure out this strange behavior.

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: How did you compile it? Likely cause is that the compiled class files are not in the same directory as where Intellij thinks when making.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the class is excluded from compilation - I think I've had this before.

Try: `Settings` -> `Compiler` -> `Excludes`

Comment: It is really solution. I'll accept answer later. But how this happen?

Comment: An unlikely guess; you hit Alt+Enter to import a class, the class was not found but rather than importing you accidentally excluded the class. I've come close to doing this when rushing through imports.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just spent the past 3 hours going insane

Answer (score 8):

Please try to rename the file name with suffix ".java" eventhough it is within the same package, if you insert this file as a java source file. Intellij is not intelligent in this aspect, it will not recognize it in the package without a suffix, and it is really stupid :-)

Comment: Correct solution for me, been pulling my hair for the past few hours. What a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without more details. Both classes, you project configuration, tools you are using, etc....

But definitely your class JDBCDAOFactory don't see your TeamDAO class.

What I will do:
- check modifiers - visibility (should be ok while you have as it looks that you have both in same package)

- try to use TeamDAO in other class (for instance DBUtil)